# The contractor ExpandableListAdapter...is undefined

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I seem to be having an issue with a single line of code in my Fragment that holds the Expandable ListView. This thing is, I followed this tutorial on how to create one http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/ which creates it in an activity. I got this working correctly in a different workspace within an activity.

Now I am trying to implement the same code within a fragment. I have been left with one error for days. Below is the first bit of code for the Expandable ListView.

**SuikodenFragment.java**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

public class SuikodenFragment extends Fragment {

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;
List<String> listDataHeader;
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.suikoden_main_activity1, container, false);
    // you can use findViewById() using the above 'view'
    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.suikodenList1);

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData();

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);

    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    return rootView;
}
```

The error is - 
The constructor ExpandableListAdapter(SuikodenFragment, List, HashMap>) is undefined

On this line -

```
listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the context to the ExpandableListAdapter. You are trying to pass the fragment with 'this':

```
   listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, listDataHeader, listDataChild);
```

instead, use the following:

```
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);
```

or

```
    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(getActivity(), listDataHeader, listDataChild);
```